# Replacing power window motor in a 2003 Corolla

Tags: toyota, power-windows, motors

What should it cost (parts and labor) to replace a power window motor in a 2003 Toyota Corolla? What should I consider when deciding between factory vs. used vs. aftermarket?

Answer (score 3):

You never know where used parts come from, unless you remove them, and even then you never know their state. I would suggest a new one, and hopefully from a reputable manufacturer. Also, I rarely saw motors go bad, as it was usually the window regulator that failed and would seize the window. The labor is usually around the same, but motors are about 3 times the cost of the regulator on most vehicles.

Comment: Same here in regards to the motors.  Haven't seen a bad one yet, but several bad switches...